# Zooming bootstrap card without affecting next card in a row

Tags: css

I want the card element to get zoomed on hover. The problem is, there are cards whiled is looped and displayed in a row. While zooming a particular card, the immediate right card affects the zooming card by overlapping.

I've tried giving position:absolute in CSS. It doesn't work out.
I didn't find expected solution on web.

Below is my code:

```css
.card-collection 
{
    display: flex;
}

.card 
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    border: 1px solid red;
    
}

.card:hover
{ 
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
 
      <div class="card-collection">

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="text-center"> Aravind </h5>
            <p>Chennai</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="text-center"> Ravi </h5>
            <p>Chennai</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="text-center"> Aravind </h5>
            <p>Chennai</p>
          </div>
        </div>
       
      </div>
```

Actually I'm working on Angular. This is what I'm getting as output:[image]

Comment: have you tried `position: absolute; z-index: 111;` ? z-index property is important in this scenario

Comment: it works!Thanks @BabakHabibi

Comment: I'm new to web development.I want to know why the value of z-index to be 111?@BabakHabibi

Comment: happy to help :)
111 is just a sample if you put 1 it's working I just for making sure said 111 , the default z-index of elements in HTML is 0 but in some cases (for example if you using bootstrap) maybe some elements has not z-index 0 , so for making sure I told you put 111

Comment: I tried changing value to 1 , it didn't worked for bottom left card. So, thought 111 has meaning.

Comment: the more value you put the more you make sure it works correctly but you should remember the structue of your codes so you can manage it for later

Comment: Got it. Thanks again @BabakHabibi

Answer (score 0):

Use this, I have used background: #fff; just for demo, you can remove it while using

> The `position: initial` CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an element. I am using it in order to make the z-index effective.

```css
.card-collection 
{
    display: flex;
}

.card 
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    border: 1px solid red;
    
}

.card:hover
{ 
  transform: scale(2);
  position:initial;
  z-index:111;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-collection">

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="text-center"> Aravind </h5>
            <p>Chennai</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="text-center"> Ravi </h5>
            <p>Chennai</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="text-center"> Aravind </h5>
            <p>Chennai</p>
          </div>
        </div>
       
      </div>
```

Comment: it works ! if the position is set to absolute it works perfect. Thanks @ charan kumar @Babak